# Weighted Average of Complex Numbers Separates Points

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I have been stuck on the following problem and am mostly looking for any hints/ techniques that could be helpful.

Let $ \{z_k\}_{k=1}^n \subset\mathbb{C} $ be distinct points and $ a_k>0 $ for $ 1\leq k \leq n $. Assume $ \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=1 $ and define $ z=\sum_{k=1}^{n}m_kz_k $. Prove that every line $ l $ through $ z $ separates the points $ \{z_k\}_{k=1}^n $ unless all of them are collinear. Here separates  means that there are points on both sides of the line $ l $ without being on $ l $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_k$ be the coordinate of $z_k$ on an axis that is not parallel to $\ell.$ Then the coordinate $u$ of the weighted average $z$ is the weighted average of $u_k$ for $k=1,\ldots,n.$ So the proposition says you can't have $u_k > u$ for every $k$ or $u_k<u$ for every $k.$

Answer (score 1):

The point $$z$$ will lie inside the convex hull. Therefore every line cuts the convex hull into two parts.

This will fail when the hull is empty, ie, the points are collinear